# How can I run a command from inside another stack command?

Tags: function, callback, stack, command, livecode

I have a callback handler in a stack that looks for telemetry data.  When it gets some, I parse it and then want to save it. However, to save it requires other functions and commands in the same stack.

I could put it on the card, but where? I use the openCard end openCard and that's about it in the card.

The stack has all the functions and commands I need. There's no button to press to run the save code - I need it to run automatically.

How can I put the chunk of code on the card and then have the stack 'call it'?

I know how to call commands from the card, but not from the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generically, you simply call either a command handler or a function handler in-line:

```
on mouseUp -- a "main" handler
  doSomething -- a command handler 
  dosomethingElse -- another command handler 
  put doYetAnotherThing(paramList) into field 1 -- a function handler
end mouseUp

on doSomething
  well, do something
end doSomething

on doSomethingElse
  you get the picture
  ...
```

Try making a simple main handler that does silly trivial things for each of the three "subRoutine" calls above. You will be an expert in a matter of hours.
The placement of the three has to be managed. Generally, they reside in the script where the main handler lives. But they can be anywhere in LC.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a handler in a card (or any other control) from another script, you can use one of the following commands:

- **dispatch** "*command*" to *control* with *param1*, *param2*, …
- **send** "*command*" to *control* [in *time*]
- put **value**(*command*, *control*) into tResult

Dispatch happily continues even if the *command* isn't handled by the *control*. You can check that of course.
Send has the advantage that you can schedule the sending forwards in time, but is a bit harder if you want to also send some parameters.
Value is good candidate if you call a function and want the result back.

Answer (score 0):

Note that ""openCard" and "preOpenCard" messages can be trapped and worked in the stack script, as long as there are no such handlers in the card script. And even if there are, you can "pass" each message after the card script handler is done with it";

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a command on the stack that is called every X times while the user is on that card. This command must be called to itself and to the other manipulators that you use to obtain the data. This same manipulator will be in charge of saving the data.

```
# Code on the card
local sTelemetryData

on openCard
 // If the card belongs to the pile where all the telemetry is or if this pile is a library.
 getTelemetryData
// otherwise you will have to call the getTelemetryData command. You can use send, disparsh, or call.
// call "getTelemetryData" to stack "stack name"
end openCard

# Code on the stack
constant kTime = 100
local sPendingMessageID

on getTelemetryData
   
   if the short name of this card is not "TelemetryData"
   then exit getTelemetryData
   
   if sPendingMessageID is a number
   then cancel sPendingMessageID
   
   // call the commands and functions that look up the telemetry data.
   // The data must be stored in the sTelemetryData variable to save it and at once use this variable as a flag
  
   if sTelemetryData is not empty then
      // The data is sent to be saved
   end if
   
put empty into sTelemetryData
   send "getTelemetryData" to me in kTime milliseconds
   put the result into sPendingMessageID
end getTelemetryData
```